# Error:cordova build command error

Tags: cordova

what is the meaning of this error?i tried running the cordova build command and this is the error that shows

```
C:\Users\Dan\alaya>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Dan\alaya\platforms\android   \cordova \build.
bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
Running: C:\Users\Dan\alaya\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b    C:\Users\
Dan\alaya\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk
1.8.0_40\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

C:\Users\Dan\alaya\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
               throw e;
                ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\Dan\alaya\platforms an
 droid\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Dan\alaya\platforms\android         \build.gradle
 Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
 ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed  with \\exit  code
1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in setting JAVA_HOME. Change

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
```

to

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
```

Comment: but will my java still work with that variable name?

Comment: Yes java will work. If you want to use java via command line then add  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin  in path variable.

Comment: @Nasru-DeenSaani  you're welcome) of it was helpfull, you may accept and upvote the answer.